# "Timers cannot have negative intervals" pops up when installing from apt

Tags: apt, software-installation

So, I just installed Ubuntu yesterday, together with my main Windows just so I could use it for development. Because of all the keys, I would be typing I thought why not install Whatpulse to keep track of them? But turns out it is a tedious task. So, basically, I followed this guide: [Whatpulse (installation guide Ubuntu 14.04)](https://www.skenz.it/cs/whatpulse), because there isn't anything that is newer.

**NOTE:** I do use the generic version from the installs.

So, basically this is what I did (after extracting the .gz file of course):

```
sudo ./setup-input-permissions.sh
sudo apt-get install libqtcore4
sudo apt-get install libqtscript4-core
sudo apt-get install libqt4-sql 
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev
sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip ./whatpulse
```

And then I tried

```
./whatpulse
```

But it gave me this error:

> ./whatpulse: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Sql.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

What does it mean? After a bit of searching I found that by reinstalling and doing this the problem might be resolved:

```
sudo strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
```

But it still gives the same error. By the way, I didn't install the `libqtwebkit4` library because it isn't listed at the [official site](https://help.whatpulse.org/kb/client/linux-installation).

I'm usually at StackOverflow, so I don't know the tags here. If anybody can fix them that would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:**

Thanks to @KnudLarsen, I solved the first error. So, now when I try to run `./whatpulse` at least it attempts to open it.But the error that it gives me is:

```
23-04-2020 07:56:37.334  INFO "Starting WhatPulse 2.8.4-1633..." 
QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot have negative intervals
23-04-2020 07:56:37.513 DEBUG Database file: "/home/usr/.local/share/WhatPulse/whatpulse.db" 
Application crashed with signal 11!
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've read this on the WhatPulse forums, but the solution doesn't seem to exist. The only thing they refer to is that quote-on-quote:

> WhatPulse doesn't work with Linux anymore, due to some fundamental changes in Linux. There is no confirmed fix date, and there has been no official update from the developer in over a year.

Comment: Install "libQt5Sql.so.5" : `sudo apt install libqt5sql5`

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks I tried that and now the WhatPulse opening process at least gets initiated. But now it is telling me that `Application crashed with signal 11!`.  I'll see the log file and report.